# Is there any other advantage of lambdas besides convenience?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

The title might not be precise but I couldn't think of any brief one that would be. *(Feel free to suggest one or edit my question.)*

I was wondering if there is any other advantage of using lambda functions other than the fact that that one doesn't have to explicitly define (and write) the whole class definition of a functor or define a separate function to be used (possibly) just once. In other words, are lambdas introduced just for convenience or is there more to them?

Edit:
One thing to add to my question. Lambdas allow programmer to write less, do it more conveniently and **therefore they are less error-prone**. Which in itself is a different thing/reason than just convenience but is associated with it.

Comment: AFAIK they're just syntactic sugar.  But I might be mistaken.

Comment: One good thing they do is they help when editing code. If you later delete that piece of code, you might forget to the delete the function, but with lambdas, it is inside the code segment.

Comment: It removes duplication (and therefore scope for error) when capturing variables.

Comment: I think your question is a bit too vague. Is there any advantage to a high level language like C++ over directly writing machine code other than convenience? Is there any advantage to C++ over C other than convenience?

Comment: Remember than convenience is the main reason we have different languages besides assembly. The ability to abstract aways factors of computing is the driving power of modern higher level languages.

Comment: They make the code unintelligible while making the programmer appear to be more sophisticated.

Answer (score 9):

See full motivation for lamdas at [A proposal to add lambda functions to the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1958.pdf)
:

> C++ Standard Library algorithms would be much more pleasant to use if C++ had support for lambdas. Lambda functions would let people use C++ Standard Library algorithms in many cases where currently it is easier to write a for loop. Many developers do not use function objects simply because of the syntactic overhead.

Comment: Ok, I read it and it all revolves around having to write less code and convenience.

Comment: @NPS True, they mostly elaborate this point in that paper.

Answer (score 5):

Lambdas are largely syntactic sugar, but not entirely.  One point about lambdas is that they capture arrays by direct-initialization in subscript order **[expr.prim.lambda]**:

> 22 - [...] (For array members, the array elements are direct-initialized in increasing
>   subscript order.) [...]

This is surprisingly difficult to achieve otherwise; it is necessary to construct an index parameter pack using something like `std::index_sequence` and the semantics are not quite the same.

Another thing lambdas can do is to capture a (variadic) parameter pack; this cannot be done generically (since structure members cannot be a parameter pack expansion) except via something like `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 3):

**Basically: They exist for your convenience.**

In addition to Maxim's answer, according to the [MSDN article about Lambda Expressions in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx):

> When you write code, you probably use function pointers and function
> objects to solve problems and perform calculations, especially when
> you use STL algorithms. Function pointers and function objects have
> advantages and disadvantages—for example, function pointers have
> minimal syntactic overhead but do not retain state within a scope, and
> function objects can maintain state but require the syntactic overhead
> of a class definition.
>
> A lambda combines the benefits of function
> pointers and function objects and avoids their disadvantages. Like a
> function objects, a lambda is flexible and can maintain state, but
> unlike a function object, its compact syntax doesn't require a class
> definition. By using lambdas, you can write code that's less
> cumbersome and less prone to errors than the code for an equivalent
> function object.

Comment: I read that before I posted my question and from what I understand the only benefit they mention here is the one I stated in my question.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft- not suprisingly -isn't so much focused on philosophy in their MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The one advantage to captureless lambdas over the corresponding function object is that they are convertible to function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

- Using STL algorithms becomes more convenient.
- If you want to write
  reusable code in your function but might not make sense to put it in
  a free function, then lambdas come to the rescue.

For eg.

```
void foo()
{
    auto validate = [] (const std::string& str) -> bool { // do some validation. };
    /// ... code.
    if (!validate("some info"))
    {
       // throw error;
    }

    ////  

     validate("some other info");
}
```